# Zhonya and Jannas ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Haven't had a chance to try this myself since I don't have any friends that play LoL.

But here is my question: If you, for example, use Zhonya's Ring as Kennen, and Janna uses her ulti while Zhonya's is active, does it still push Kennen away, or does it work like Vlad's pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: if you use Zhonya's Hourglass BEFORE Janna ultimate. You will **NOT** move. besides that, you will [fly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTahrYXCChI)!!!

From [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Zhonya%27s_Hourglass)

**Zhonya's Hourglass**

> Unique: Places your champion into stasis for 2 seconds, rendering you
>   invulnerable and untargetable but unable to take any actions. 90
>   second cooldown.

**Monsoon**

> (Active): Janna knocks surrounding enemies back and channels healing
>   winds, restoring health to nearby allies each half second, for 4
>   seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Champions protected by Zhonya's ring are immune to all CC, and this includes the initial pushback from Janna's Monsoon.

Kennen will not move.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Ken and you use your hourglass BEFORE Janna's ultimate you stop where you are standing and he wind will NOT blow you back. However you will remain stationary during the time you use the hourglass.